# Android Slow Cold Start Times

Tags: android, android-activity, time, android-inflate, cold-start

I am having a very odd problem that I need assistance solving. It has to do with long application cold start times. Meaning, it takes a long time for my application to startup and get displayed for the first time. I have looked into troubleshooting given the material given here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

All very helpful but I tried something different. When our system is under heavy load is when I see the startup time issues. I tried stripping the entire activity to just launching only, no painting/inflating of views what-so-ever. Literally just launching the base activity. I see cold start time on average of 1.45s. You may think that this is OK, but we have other applications that have full implementations and actual inflations of views/widgets, data etc.. that only take around 1.17s to launch. This is very confusing to me since I literally just have an activity only (same android theme). What other things should I be looking for? Why would it take so long to start up?

Note that the activity that I am comparing it against is built using Gradle while I am using Maven. Our Android manifests are the same in terms of attribute usage.

I also tried having the process already started before launching the activity (created a dummy service on bootup) but there was no real improvement in launch time. I am on Android 4.3.1 and am confirming launch time by looking at the ActivityManager entry in logcat. Maybe a resource loading issue? It has to be something with the build since theres not reason why a bare bones activity takes longer to launch then one that is much more complex.

EDIT: adding code

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="debug-11" package="com.my.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.cnh.android.permission.ACCESS_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <!-- uses-sdk is updated automatically by pom.xml -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>


    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".App" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name=".MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Application code:

```
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * base App class used for application
 */
public class App extends Application {

   private static Context context;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      setContext(this);
   }

   private static void setContext(Context ctx) {
      context = ctx;
   }

   public static Context getContext() {
      return context;
   }
}
```

Activity code:

```
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
   }
}
```

Like I said, super basic/skeleton.

Comment: Do you have a class that extends android.app.Application ? If that's the case, it might be because you are doing too much stuff in there

Comment: try profiling your app to see where it goes wrong. it's the best solution for such problems

Comment: There is an App that extends Application. But there isn't anything done in there. Just a blank entry that has an override to onCreate and then just calls the super.

Comment: method profile? I have used that before but what am I looking for? I know I shouldn't see anything for launching inflating views since I am literally just launching a bare Activity.

Comment: can you post some code? we can't help you like that

Comment: @hanaa edited and added. Like I said, super basic so no idea why it takes so long vs an activity (implemented the same way) with UI logic.

Comment: do you have any external libs added to your project? if so try without them or try building in release mode to see if it solves it

Comment: Yes, we have a lot of external libs. This is something I will try. Does it have unpack all these libs once the activity launches?

Comment: So, removing every single dependency and external lib. It has a start time of 645 ms. Is that normal for a blank activity?

Comment: Also, that is when I setup a dummy service as well that gets launched on boot so that the process is present. If I remove the service (process not started until I launch the activity) its more like 950ms

Comment: I started added libs back and when I add in a native lib (.so) of mine it jumps to the low end of 645 ms (no libs, process already started before launching activity for the first time) to on average 1.02s.

Comment: just an update, did a gradle build and the time for a bar bones activity shrunk dramatically. Launch time is 350ms. How is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why Maven built apk launches slower than a Gradle built apk? Even when using same code-set and dependencies?